# Something wrong with redirects on my Joomla 1.5.18 site

Tags: url, redirect, authentication, joomla

My Joomla 1.5.18 site, I enabled login, when I click login the page I get sent to is NOT styled with CSS. If I login it redirects to the home page and it is not styled anymore either.
It looks like it is recursively appending stuff to the URL incorrectly.

```
http://www.myjoomlasite.org/index.php/index.php/login
```

if I click on home page or login links it keeps putting more and more index.php entries in the URL, and sometimes on the end. The following is what I get when I try and go to a JEvents menu item.

```
http://www.myjoomlasite.org/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/upcomingevents/month.calendar/2010/06/09/index.php
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I don't know what to search for on Google apparently, and none of the Joomla! books I have address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I had turned on `Search Engine Friendly URLs` in `SEO Settings` under `Global Configuration`. Turning this back off fixed the problem. Now I guess another question will be along the lines on how to get the Search Engine Friendly URL's to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link to stylesheets and images using a link that starts with a leading slash and therefore counts from the root.

It is the browser that evaluates the URL for those resources, based on the URL of the currently viewed HTML page.  Never use relative links for these resources.